# How do I channel a cable behind a skirting board when fitting a back box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ethernet, cable-management, skirting

I have a 1930s British house with skirting boards, I want to run Ethernet from some points around the house, I have got the cable under the floorboards, but I now need to cut out some back boxes, I have managed to re-purpose an existing satellite port that I wont ever use to be ethernet, but the other rooms do not have any spare wall sockets.

I think I understand how to cut the hole for the back box by drilling and chiselling out. What im struggling to find advice on, is how do I channel a hole behind the skirting board without damaging it or the wall? A long drill bit I would still be at an angle?

I don't want to take off the skirting board as I would 100% damage it and its already painted.

This is the one I re-purposed in the front room.

[image: Skirting Backbox]

Comment: A photo of the actual place you want to work on would help. Also it is unclear to me what you mean by  channel behind, do want to feed a wire up from below  or in from the front to a electrical box ?

Answer (score 1):

You would drill from below with a long bit. I assume you wall is typical studs with drywall or plaster. You should be able to get enough angle for the hole to come out in the wall. Do this before you insert the box. Then you can run your wire into the box before mounting it.

Comment: My walls seem to be made of brick with plaster, my upstairs (where I will be doing the wall boxes) don't have under floor depth like I do downstairs in this photo, so I cut out the box first and drill up from under! How did I not think of that, any more tips on making the box cutout in the first place? I'm brand new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand. You want the two grey wires that come from the left and go into the hole in the floor to be hidden ??

[Surface mounted cable channel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BLQPVFD).

There is corresponding surface mounted boxes that go with the channel so no holes need to be drilled.

If you did not want the surface mounted stuff then taking the trim off and routing a channel in the back of the trim board with a router would work. ( make sure you do not nail through the cable )